# SharePoint doesn't add a new Font

Tags: 2013, google-fonts

I am trying to add a new font to the Font Selection Menu in the Page Editor.

I have following CSS-Code for the new Font:

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine");

.ms-rteFontFace-14
{
     -ms-name: "Tangerine";
     font-family: "Tangerine";
}
```

And the following call in the masterpage:

```
<link type="text/css" href="../../SiteAssets/MainStyle.css">
```

Now if I refresh the page after uploading these two files the editor still shows the default fonts and not my custom one.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44418/discussion-on-question-by-snickbrack-sharepoint-doesnt-add-a-new-font).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work well with SharePoint 2010 , to let it working properly with SharePoint 2013 just change the class name from  `.ms-rteFontFace-12` to `.ms-rteFontFace-custom1`

So the final CSS code should be

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine");

.ms-rteFontFace-custom1
{
     -ms-name: "Tangerine";
     font-family: "Tangerine";
}
```

Check also the details steps with image [at Add Font Faces to Format Text in SharePoint 2013 Ribbon using CSS](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/08/25/add-fontfaces-format-text-sharepoint2013-ribbon-css/)